# Magento CE Upgraded from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.0 - Multi-Store - theme switches logos

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, multistore

I just updated a Magento CE site from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.0. This is a multi-store site. Two stores, two domain names, one Magento installation, one server. And these stores, this Magento installation, has been working fine for a long time.

After what seemed a smooth and successful update to 1.9.2.0 I noticed that seemingly at random one of the two sites will display the logo and a footer banner from the 'other' store.

There are two separate themes set up - one for each store. The multi-store is implemented using a separate directory for the second store with it's own index.php file (also updated manually as part of the 1.9.2.0 update) and all other directories are symbolic links back to the main Magento installation.

At time A, store 1 displays the theme for store 1 and the logo and footer banner for store 1. AND store 2 displays the theme for store 2 the logo and footer banner for store 1. If time passes or I refresh the cache or some other random event occurs then...

At time B, store 1 displays the theme for store 1 the logo and footer banner for store 2 AND store 2 displays the theme for store 2 the logo and footer banner for store 2.

Each store always shows the correct theme (store 1 and store 2 themes are distinctly different). But they randomly (seemingly) show a logo image and footer banner that is incorrect.

It is worth noting that both the logo image and footer banner are defined in CMS static blocks. So each store has a static block for the header logo and one for the footer banner.

I would appreciate any brainstorming ideas on how to quickly identify and resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this problem. May not be the best way. First I investigated issues with the .htaccess and index.php files, but nothing I tried there solved anything.

The answer was that I modified the identifiers for the CMS static blocks that contain the store 2 logo, banners, and related information. Then I modified the store 2 theme (layout/local.xml to handle the updated identifiers and templates/page/html [multiple files] that referenced these static block identifiers).

The store 1 and store 2 CMS static block identifiers were the same (e.g. header_graphics and footer_banner), but of course were set as valid only for the appropriate store 1 or store 2. This seems to be the source of the problem. But it used to work fine prior to the 1.9.2.0 update. The new identifiers were set with a prefix for store 2 (e.g. x2_header_graphics and x2_footer_banner). So now there is no way that the store 1 theme could erroneously find those static blocks.

If someone else has a similar problem I hope this is helpful. I don't know (and probably won't have time to figure out) whether this is a Magento bug or simply a bad practice on my part. If anyone has an opinion I'll be interested to hear it.